# Parse self as list, not string

Tags: python, npyscreen

Still trying to figure out this code im building and make it work cross-platform.
I have a couple defining factors, that the code in question references, so I will input them all.

```py
self.mainFile = r"\SYS64"
self.dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
self.mainOSProgram = "python " + self.dir_path + self.mainFile + r"\jdosos.py"
```

Ive gotten it to work with

```
subprocess.Popen(["python",r'\Users\Terra Byte\Desktop\jdos3\JDOS3\SYS64\jdosos.py'])
```

but that defines a path, when I would like the path to be defined by the code, so it can work wherever the program is installed.

I get the same error, `python: can't open file 'C:\Users\Terra': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

If I `print(self.mainOSProgram)`, This is the result.

```
python C:\Users\Terra Byte\Desktop\jdos3\JDOS3\SYS64\jdosos.py
```

Which is the correct filepath, but its paring as a string, so it breaks the statement at the first space.

Comment: You want to pass a list as `Popen`'s first argument - `"python"` followed by your calculated file path.  When you use `shell=False` and pass a list of parameters, spaces (and other oddities) in the individual parameters are no problem.

Comment: @jasonharper Not entirely sure how i would implement `shell=False`. `python` is the first word in `self.mainOSProgram` so, i think it is already defined.

Comment: Don't make it the first word.  Make it a separate item in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print(self.mainOSProgram)` outputs string as is, so you get spaces. If you try to add quotes to your command it will work.
`python "C:\Users\Terra Byte\Desktop\jdos3\JDOS3\SYS64\jdosos.py"`

Regarding the code I would use `os.path.join` to construct the path

```py
import subprocess
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

executable_path = os.path.join(dir_path, "SYS64", "jdosos.py")
subprocess.Popen(["python", executable_path])
```

Comment: The sommand diddnt seem to work properly, this is the CMD output when calling the `subprocess`. `C:\Users\Terra Byte\Desktop\jdos3\JDOS3>C:\Users\Terra Byte\Desktop\jdos3\JDOS3>`

Comment: I don't understand your comment. This snippet works. I tested it with a path with spaces.

Comment: This is the printed output of `executable_path` For some reason it dosent seem to be adding `"python"` to it. `C:\Users\Terra Byte\Desktop\jdos3\JDOS3\SYS64\jdosos.py`

Comment: This is correct because subprocess has "python" in it. `subprocess.Popen(["python", executable_path])`

Comment: Even if i add `"python"` to `executable_path` it still prints without it. Perhaps it is conflicting with `npyscreen`? i wouldn't see any reason why it would. edit: It is conflicting with `npyscreen` I have no idea why, but if i use the provided code outside of `npyscreen`, it works fine.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I never work with `npyscreen`. Might be some specifics of your setup.

Comment: Im gonna go ahead and mark this as an answer because it works outside of the code i did not provide. I will do some poking around and try to figure out why it diddnt work in `npyscreen`